# has_secure_password doesnt work on JSON but it does when form for

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I'm using the method

```
has_secure_password
```

on my user model which i understand creates two virtual fields:

```
Password 
Password_confirmation
```

and validates the precense of them, so by my side i'm doing these others validations:

```
validates :password  , length: {minimum: 6} 
validates :password_confirmation  , length: {minimum: 6}
```

in my  view i have this form:

```
<%= form_for :user, url:{controller: 'users', action: 'create'}, html:{class:"form-horizontal"}  do |f| %>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label(:name, "Nombre", class:"control-label col-sm-1") %>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
          <%= f.text_field(:name, class:"form-control") %>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group ">
              <%= f.label(:last_name, "Apellido", class:"control-label col-sm-1") %>
              <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <%= f.text_field(:last_name,  class:"form-control ") %>
              </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group ">
              <%= f.label(:cellphone, "Celular", class:"control-label col-sm-1") %>
              <div class="col-sm-3">
              <%= f.text_field(:cellphone, class:"form-control") %>
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group ">
              <%= f.label(:phone, "Telefono", class:"control-label col-sm-1") %>
              <div class="col-sm-3">
              <%= f.text_field(:phone, class:"form-control") %>
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group ">
              <%= f.label(:address, "Direccion", class:"control-label col-sm-1") %>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
              <%= f.text_field(:address, class:"form-control") %>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="form-group ">
              <%= f.label(:email, "Correo", class:"control-label col-sm-1") %>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <%= f.text_field(:email, class:"form-control") %>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group ">
            <%= f.label(:password, "Contraseña", class:"control-label col-sm-1") %>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <%= f.password_field(:password, class:"form-control") %>
            </div>
        </div>

      <div class="form-group ">
        <%= f.label(:password_confirmation, "Confirmar Contraseña", class:"control-label col-sm-1") %>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <%= f.password_field(:password_confirmation, class:"form-control") %>
        </div>
      </div>

        <div class="form-group ">
            <%= f.label(:city_id, "Ciudad", class:"control-label col-sm-1") %>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                 <%= f.select(:city_id, @cities.map {|c| [c.name, c.id]}) %>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="form-buttons">
            <%= submit_tag("Create Section") %>
        </div>

  <% end %>
```

and the controller has these actions:

```
def create

@user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to controller: "users", action: "show"

    else
      @cities = City.all
      render 'new'
    end
  end

private

     def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:name, :last_name, :email, :address, :password,    :password_confirmation, :cellphone, :city_id, :phone)
      end
```

so when the user submmit the the form the user gets created with the encrypted password under the field password_digest and it works fine.

my actual problem its with a controller wich let the client create a new user by sending a json, this is the method for the api controller:

```
respond_to :json

def create
    respond_with User.create(user_params)
end 

private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :last_name, :email, :address, :password, :password_confirmation, :cellphone, :city_id, :phone)
  end
```

when i send this JSON:

```
var ad = {

            name:"juan",
            last_name:"paco",
            cellphone:"1234567890",
            phone:"1234567890",
            address:"porche",
            password:"porche",
            password_confirmation:"porche",
            email:"kkk@hj.com",
            city_id: 1,

        };
```

to

```
localhost.com:3000/api/v1/users/create
```

i get :

```
{"errors":{"password":["can't be blank","is too short (minimum is 6 characters)"],"password_confirmation":["is too short (minimum is 6 characters)"]}}
```

Comment: `password` and `password_confirmation` have single quotes instead of double.  Is that significant?

Comment: @GraemeMcLean i don't think so, it was just me trying something... and it dind't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this issue has to do with Parameter Wrapping http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html

Since your json parameters are not under a root node (and you probably have parameter wrapping turned on in config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb), the fields are automatically being wrapped in an root with the same name as the controller (`user`). Since `password` is a virtual attribute and is not returned by `attribute_names` it is not wrapped:

> On ActiveRecord models with no :include or :exclude option set, it
>   will only wrap the parameters returned by the class method
>   attribute_names.

I think the correct solution here is to either specify `password` in the `include` list of `wrap_parameters` by adding this to the top of your `UsersController`

```
wrap_parameters include: User.attribute_names + [:password]
```

or make the JSON request with a `user` root node

```
var ad = { 
          user: 
          {
            name:"juan",
            last_name:"paco",
            cellphone:"1234567890",
            phone:"1234567890",
            address:"porche",
            password:"porche",
            password_confirmation:"porche",
            email:"kkk@hj.com",
            city_id: 1
          }
        };
```

Comment: Thanks but i don't get the second option with the JSON request with a user root node, i see the same json i'm sending...

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution, maybe no te most practical but it does the work...

I'va changed the create method to:

```
 def create
    new_parms = user_params
    new_parms[:password] = params[:password]
    new_parms[:password_confirmation] = params[:password_confirmation]
    respond_with User.create(new_parms)
  end
```

because i was checking the rails server log and i saw a few diferrences in the params on the html request and the params on the JSON request.

when someone submmit a form i get this:

```
Started POST "/users/create" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-09 16:56:07 -0400
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"5HZn9RRbdNAzSirAb9FauNYj/Jr/AAkKBecTvzrih/8=", "user"=>{"name"=>"", "last_name"=>"", "cellphone"=>"", "phone"=>"", "address"=>"", "email"=>"", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "city_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Create Section"}
```

when i sent a JSON request i get this:

```
Started GET "/api/v1/users/creando" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-09 16:58:34 -0400
Processing by API::V1::UsersController#creando as JSON
  Parameters: {"name"=>"juan", "last_name"=>"paco", "cellphone"=>"1234567890", "phone"=>"1234567890", "address"=>"porche", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"kkk@hj.com", "city_id"=>1, "commit"=>"Create Section", "authenticity_token"=>"5HZn9RRbdNAzSirAb9FauNYj/Jr/AAkKBecTvzrih/8=", "user"=>{"name"=>"juan", "last_name"=>"paco", "cellphone"=>"1234567890", "phone"=>"1234567890", "address"=>"porche", "email"=>"kkk@hj.com", "city_id"=>1}}
```

i think this is for the form_for wich create a instance of the User object while de JSON doesn't can anyone tell me why this fix it?